# Why does this DataOutputStream print gibberish after my name?

Tags: java, file-io, dataoutputstream

everything in the question is in the title.

there's a lot of gibberish after "my name" in the output.

```
import java.io.*;

public class DOStry {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String file = "file.txt";
    String stra = "my name";
    int intb = 1;
    double douc = 2.5;
   char chad = 'f';

    try
    {

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

        dos.writeUTF(stra);
        //i don't know why it prints gibberish after my name. 
        dos.writeInt(intb);
        dos.writeDouble(douc);
        dos.writeChar(chad);

        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

        }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("IOException : " + e);
    }

    }
}
```

i'm not good, what have i missed?  i'm just trying to learn DataOutputStream.

Comment: *"... what have i missed?"* - The obvious thing that DataOutputString is for writing binary data not text!!

Answer (score 3):

DataOutputStream is for printing binary, not text and you must read it as a binary file to make sense of it.  The fact you can read portions of it as if it were text doesn't mean it is.

I suggest you do the following.  These can all be read as text.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

pw.println(stra);
pw.println(intb);
pw.println(douc);
pw.println(chad);

dos.close();
```

In short, if you mix binary and text, you are more likely to get yourself confused.